# Override overflow for gwt DockLayoutPanel widgets

Tags: css, gwt, overflow, uibinder, docklayoutpanel

I'm creating a page with a navigation menu on the left, containing icons for each section.
The page layout looks something like this:

```
  <g:DockLayoutPanel unit="PX">
    <g:west size="55"><g:SimplePanel ui:field="navigation" /></g:west>
    <g:center>
      <g:ScrollPanel>
        <g:Whatever ui:field="content" />
      </g:ScrollPanel>
    </g:center>
  </g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

Hovering on each of the icons of the navigation bar is supposed to show a balloon containing the title of the item, and some sub-items.
I achieved the effect by CSS, giving each balloon a position relative to its icon.

The g:west element is rendered as

```
<div style="
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 55px; ">
```

My problem is that `overflow: hidden`.

How do I tell the DockLayoutPanel that it is OK for the west element to overflow over the center element?

**Edit:**
I found a workaround which is quite reliable

```
navigation.getElement().getParentElement().getParentElement().getStyle()
    .setOverflow(Overflow.VISIBLE);
```

Does anybody know a solution which doesn't mess with HTML elements?

Comment: I saw this (answer at the bottom):

https://github.com/gwtbootstrap/gwt-bootstrap/issues/231

basically it sais one should set the height of your navigation-Panel to 100%:

<g:SimplePanel ui:field="navigation" height="100%"/>

However, I didn't try it...

Comment: thank you @djjeck for your workaround, worked for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override inlined style of the north div:

```
<ui:style>
    .dockLayoutPanel > div {
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
</ui:style>

<g:DockLayoutPanel unit="PX" width="100%" height="100%" addStyleNames="{style.dockLayoutPanel}">
    <g:north size="46">
     ...
    </g:north>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

Tested with GWT 2.6.1.

You could find more suggestions here: https://github.com/gwtbootstrap/gwt-bootstrap/issues/231

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use the [PopupPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html) showing a custom balloon widget, styled accordingly. You can then handle your navigation icons' `MouseOverEvent` and `MouseOutEvent` to set up the content of, show and hide your balloon.

Comment: That's a valid alternative, although I feel safer relying on relative CSS positioning for placing my balloons next to the buttons, rather than calculating coordinates via JS.